# 'File upload' button on HTML adds time+date only if the picture was taken horizontally, not vertically. How can I make the change?

Tags: html, exif

It's just one change I need to make to make my life easier. Thing is, I'm not well versed in this. I don't think I can upload the entire thing either.

I found the area in which it might be contained. I see these buzzwords:

//ImgDate = imagedate(file);

//Get date of picture, then proceed to resize

Exit.getdata(file, function ()
ImgDate = exit. Gettag (this, "DateTime")

//Rotate and or translate if we have orientation exit data

//Write data on image
If (ImgDate != "") {

Any of these would be it?

Comment: Can you rephrase your questions well with the full codes ?

Comment: Does that phrasing make more sense? Sorry, I'm not a coder by any means but I need to learn how to make this change.

Comment: I mean what do you want to achieve?
post the html and what you have done for more clarity.